# PhpStorm 2019.2 unused element in Symfony controller

Tags: php, symfony, phpstorm

I am using PhpStorm 2019.2
In the Symfony controller, methods are highlighted as not being used.
Xdebug, then I get an error

I read on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com that this is possibly a bug, the new version of the IDE does not work correctly with annotations

```
C:\OpenServer\OSPanel\modules\php\PHP_7.2\php.exe -dxdebug.remote_enable=1 -dxdebug.remote_mode=req -dxdebug.remote_port=9090 -dxdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1 C:\OpenServer\OSPanel\domains\myblog.loc\src\Controller\IndexController.php

Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller' not found in C:\OpenServer\OSPanel\domains\myblog.loc\src\Controller\IndexController.php on line 18

Call Stack:
    0.0679     382496   1. {main}() C:\OpenServer\OSPanel\domains\myblog.loc\src\Controller\IndexController.php:0

Dump $_SERVER
   $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] is undefined
   $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] is undefined
Dump $_SESSION
   $_SESSION['*'] is undefined
Dump $_REQUEST

Process finished with exit code 255
```

Some Controller

```
class ContactController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/contact", name="contact_view")
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function contactView()
    {
        return $this->render('contact/contact.html.twig', [

        ]);
    }
}
```

At the moment, the class and its action are marked as unused in the controller, what should I do?

Comment: Nothing. Either ignore or disable this inspection.

Comment: Here is the main ticket to watch after: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-47938. Special support needs to be added into Symfony plugin so that it reports controller actions as used. Other than that -- consider disabling that inspection for your controllers or even completely.

Comment: P.S. Your attempt to debug has nothing to do with this: executing file with controller directly produces expected result (PHP error) as framework's bootstrap logic is bypassed completely.

Comment: I am also having this problem with actions in my zend-mvc controllers.

Comment: If you have a Route "...xxx/show" ... rename the function as "show" ... not showView.  This will cause PhpStorm to view it as used and not an "error".  It's a partial workaround.

Answer (score 18):

You can add your controllers and their actions as entry points. This way, those classes and methods will not be reported as dead code.

If your controllers are in `src/Controller` and your action methods have the -`Action` suffix, you can add these two rules as entry points in `Settings| Editor | Inspections`:

```
Class                    Member
/Controller/*Controller  *Action
/Controller/*Controller
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

## PHPStorm 2020

### Use *Suppressed Annotations* on `@Route`

#### The quick way

1. Hover the grayed function, or click on it and press `Alt + Enter`
2. Click on **Suppress if annotated by '@Route'**

[image: Step by step instructions animation to add suppressed route]

#### Manually

1. Go to

> Settings... > Inspections > PHP / Unused / Unused declarations > Entry points >
> Suppressed Annotations

2. Add `@Route`

[image: How to go to "settings / inspection / unused declarations / entry points / / suppressed routes". Step by step animation]

#### *Note*

*Both methods does exactly the same and you only have to it once.*

Comment: Any idea how to do it with php8 attributes `#[Route(...)]` ?

Comment: @the_nuts You normally don't need this anymore with PHPStorm. Are you still seeing the error with the last version of PHPStorm?

Answer (score 10):

The unused code inspection will not recognize this code being called since PhpStorm can not properly inspect how controllers are called in Symfony's [`HttpKernel::handleRaw()`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.4/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php#L150). Potentially this can happen with other classes, e.g. when the Service Container did not pick up the class it might not be recognized as used, yet. In Symfony projects building the cache, e.g. via `bin/console cache:clear` (which clears the old cache and warms up the new one) should help most of them, but definitely not always and not with controllers.

You can also run the inspection once on the whole project and then mark your controllers as entry points, which will automatically mark those classes as (potentially) used code. When you do this PhpStorm will add an entry to the file `.idea/misc.xml` in your project to make sure it's ignored every time.

If the high rate of false positives bothers you, you can deactivate the feature or dial it down, so it will only look at protected/private methods for instance. You can find the option under: `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Inspections | PHP | Unused`

See also: https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2019/04/locating-dead-code/

Answer (score 3):

Like the solution of @lg102 you can also define your own annotation.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug. As we wait for a fix, there is a workaround from youtrack.jetbrains.com issue [PhpStorm 2019.2 reports Symfony controller classes as unused](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-47685).

It recommends that you just disable this inspection as shown in screenshots below:

> Dmitry Tronin commented 26 Jul 2019 19:43

[image: Dmitry Tronin commented 26 Jul 2019 19:43]

> Andriy Bazanov commented 26 Jul 2019 19:44

[image: Andriy Bazanov commented 26 Jul 2019 19:44]

Disable manually from the settings
[image: Disable manually from the settings]

Reference and credit to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-47685

Comment: This isn't a solution, because it will turn off also correct unused inspections.